# Is it possible to edit an existing Blogger post with the GData API?

Tags: ruby, blogs, edit, gdata, blogger

I would like to try a Ruby gem called "blogger", but I can't find a function for editing posts on Blogger. It is stated that the full GData API is implemented in this gem.

```
http://rubydoc.info/gems/blogger
```

So what can I do to edit (and save) an already existing post on Blogger?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I realized that this gem doesn't work at all. Can't even login to google services.